# Split String evenly into Array by n - Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have a string that I want to be split into an array by 4 characters

String I have:

```
String str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
```

I want output of:

```
String[] array = ["ABCD", "EFGH", "IJKL", "MNOP"];
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Undoubtedly there is.  Have you attempted any solution on your own?

Comment: I tried, java.util.Arrays.toString(highGAccelStr.split("(?<=\\G...)")), but that gives me a String not a String[]